# jQuery Validation Difference between "numberOfinvalids()" and "invalidElements().length"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am using this jquery-validation plugin: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

I found a difference between the total error count via `.numberOfInvalids()` that is not equal to the number of invalid elements via `.invalidElements()`.

[Please see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWyFc/)

It looks like the `.errorList` is only collecting invalid elements that are clicked or visited  and as soon as you hit the submit button every element, whether it has been clicked or not, is included. As soon as you correct the first elements the errorList includes only the corrected element again.

Comment: What random validation plugin are you using?

Comment: @epascarello I'm using jQuery Validate plugin. Please see the title, the tags and the fiddle for this info.

Comment: Do you realize there are 100's of jQuery Validate Plugins?

Comment: @epascarello Would you please take a look at the 'jquery-validate' tags description? "The jQuery Validation plugin is a jQuery plugin by Jörn Zaefferer. Its purpose is to perform client-side form input validation."

Comment: I don't see `.invalidElements()` listed in the API, so part of the issue may be that method shouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: Me neither, might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've altered your fiddle a bit and added two more fields.
The number of `.invalidElements()` and `.numberOfInvalids()` is not supposed to be equal.

So if you hit one field it will show `.invalidElements(): 1` and `.numberOfInvalids() : 1`.
If you hit all the fields it will show `.invalidElements(): 1` and `.numberOfInvalids() : 4`.

If you reduce the number of invalid text fields it will then show the reduced count.

`.invalidElements()` is actually one > the form. `.numberOfInvalids()` represents each invalid field.

[**DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWyFc/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by ".invalidElements() is actually one > the form."? I'm sorry I don't understand it :)

Comment: The form is your invalid 'element' regardless of number of mistakes inside. The number of invalids however represents each possible invalid place.

Comment: But `.invalidElements()` returnes an array of elements found in th error list. Please see the implementation. It is not the form.

Comment: It returns length. Make the form correct and you will see that .invalidelements will become 0.

Comment: This is from the actual sourcecode "invalidElements: function() {
   return $(this.errorList).map(function() {
    return this.element;
   });
  },"

Comment: Good then. There might be your answer.